# Получить атрибут из Spring mergeAttributes для Thymeleaf?

Tags: bootstrap, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Делаю вылидацию!
Без //return "/main"; в POST методе не получаеться вывести ошибку под input!
Во freemarker работает!
При использовании thymeleaf нужно делать return "/main" но тогда не отображаться то что возвращает GET

```
<div th:class="${message.text} ? 'collapse show' : 'collapse' " id="collapseExample">
    <div class="form-group mt-3">
        <form th:action="@{/main}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:object="${message}" >
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="tag" placeholder="tag" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="please add message"
                       th:class="${message.text} ? 'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control ' "
                       th:field="*{text}"
                       id="myrequired"
                >
                <!-- <span class="invalid-feedback" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('text')}" th:errors="*{text}"></span>-->
                <span th:text="${textError}"></span>
            </div>

@GetMapping("/main")
public String main(
        Message message,
        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "") String filter,
        Model model) {
    Iterable<Message> messages = messagesRepo.findAll();

    if (filter != null && !filter.isEmpty()) {
        messages = messagesRepo.findByTag(filter);
    } else {
        messages = messagesRepo.findAll();
    }

    model.addAttribute("messages", messages);
    model.addAttribute( "message", message);
    model.addAttribute("filter", filter);
    return "main";
}



@PostMapping("/main")
public String addMessage(
        @AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
        @Valid Message message,
        BindingResult bindingResult,
        Model model,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    message.setAuthor(user);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        Map<String, String> errorsMap = ControllerUtil.getErrors(bindingResult);
        model.addAttribute( "message", message);
        model.mergeAttributes(errorsMap); //todo mergeAttributes не работает Validation из-за mergeAttributes

        //return "/main";

    } else {
```

..........................................
        return "redirect:/main";

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

B методе main лишняя строка `model.addAttribute( "message", message);`.

Comment: Почему эта строка лишняя? Пожалуйста уточните и [поправте ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1099887/edit).